# How to Run 1.7 Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to run scripts on a 1.7 javascript engine. The why?
I'm working with a language that is basically a forked version of 1.7 javascript but its inside of a server side box that is very slow and difficult to debug.

Comment: Um JS is backward compatible? JS 1.7 code will run in every browser/engine/whatever...

Comment: Ive just found out that JS1.7 became part of the ES6 spec, so it will run on all *modern* engines...

Answer (score 0):

Use old browsers? But that has it's own bundle of problems. If the webpages you are trying to run on this old server don't support the current Javascript language, you're better off updating the webpages instead of trying to find a way to interpret them differently.

Comment: Not old but rather new... Firefoxs JS 1.7 features became part of the spec in ES6...

Answer (score 0):

An old JavaScript engine running in a server? That might be Rhino, which you can [download here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino), and execute locally. [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/New_in_Rhino_1.7R1) says Rhino 1.7R1 implements JavaScript 1.7. Below I used oldest version I found, 1.7R4:

```
$ java -jar js.jar 
Rhino 1.7 release 4 2012 06 18
js> JSON
[object JSON]
js> JSON.stringify({x:42})
{"x":42}
js> parseInt('00012')
10
js>
```

This one has support for `JSON` so it's not too old, but it has this quirk from old JS engines where `parseInt` does not ignore leading zeroes :)

Edit:
[What is Demandware](http://www.mydevmind.nl/what-is-demandware/):

> Demandware Script is based on ECMAScript 3 with added (optional) type specification from the ECMAScript 4 proposal. On top of that the Mozilla's Javascript 1.7 extensions can be used in Demandware script.

I smell Rhino (was developed by Mozilla).

[Developing with Demandware](https://blog.baha.dk/2015/12/20/part-2-developing-demandware/):

> the way it works is that Demandware  Script is compiled into Java classes using the Rhino engine

I *see* Rhino :)

They have most certainly exposed functions that won't be available to you when using Rhino alone, but if you want to iterate quickly on custom code that does not depend on those Demandware functions (you could mock the ins & outs), then Rhino could be a good way to test your scripts.

Comment: I'll take a look at rhino, yes this is server side its part of demandware an ecommerce platform. Runs "Demandscript" which is JS 1.7 with  a couple custom functions nad stuff

Comment: @NATHANSACHS Thanks for the clarification, this seems to confirm it's Rhino